# Count the number of ways ot selecting 10 books from 3 stacks of 10 books, with a limitation

Tags: combinatorics

A library of books consists of $10$ identical English books, $10$ identical Mathematics books, and $10$ identical Sociology books.

In how many ways can $10$ books be selected off this shelf if at most one English book is selected?

Comment: Share your thoughts, please!

Comment: Hint: Two cases: $0$ English, or $1$ English. Count the number of ways for each case, add.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**:

There are either $1$ or $0$ English books selected. It's easy to count the number of possibilities for each case. Further, you will likely see a pattern that would help you find out how to calculate similar numbers of possibilities if more than one English book is allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Lay down 21 books in a circle:  1 English book followed by 10 Math books followed by 10 Sociology books.  Then pick up any 10 consecutive books.  There are 21 different ways to do this (one for each starting point), a little thought shows that each one gives a different combination, and a little more thought shows that each possible combination is accounted for.

This works, of course, only because there are only three categories of books and one of them is limited to being selected at most once.  But that's the problem, so there's the solution!